# Word Problem about no. of square inches of pizza from GRE Quant

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

Huey's Hip Pizza sells two sizes of square pizzas: a small pizza that measures $10$ inches on a side and costs $\$10$, and a large pizza that measures $15$ inches on a side and costs $\$20$. If two friends go to Huey's with $\$30$ apiece, how many more square inches of pizza can they buy if they pool their money than if they each purchase pizza alone?

**My solution:** I have solved that problem but however, my answer does not coincide with official answer. Here's my solution:

If they purchase **alone** they can buy $3$ small pizzas (in that case total area is $100\cdot 3=300$ square inches) **or** $1$ small+$1$ large (in that case total area is $100+225=325$ square inches). Hence when they purchase each pizza alone then the total area will be $2\cdot 300=600$ square inches **or** $2\cdot 325=650$.

If they purchase **together** they can buy:

(i) $6$ small pizzas then total area will be $6\cdot 100=600$

(ii) $1$ large + $4$ small then total area will be $225+4\cdot 100=625$

(iii) $2$ large + $2$ small then total area will be $2\cdot 225+2\cdot 100=650$

(iv) $3$ large then total area will be $3\cdot 225=675$

Eventually, the maximal difference is $675-600=75$.

Is my answer true?

Comment: Why are you subtracting $600$ instead of subtracting $650$?  That is not how I would interpret the question.  I would think it is "*What is the difference between the largest amount of pizza they could buy if they bought together and the largest amount of pizza they could buy if they bought separately.*"  $650$ square inches is the largest amount of pizza they could buy separately, not $600$ square inches.

Comment: If you are indeed interested in the "maximal difference" as you put it, then you are ignoring the possibility of them not buying any pizza at all.  It didn't say that they needed to use all of their money, so the least amount of pizza they could buy separately is $0$ square inches.

Comment: I think you must assume that they will be maximally efficient in their pizza spending going it alone or pooling.  $675-650 = 25$

Comment: how should I know that i need to substract the largest amount of pizza they could buy if they bought separately? In order to get maximal difference i need to substract from maximal term the least term.

Comment: It is *heavily implied* that they will be greedy and buy the most pizza possible with what money they have.  Also, I don't know where you got the phrase "maximal difference" out of this problem or what you specifically define that to mean.

Comment: @JMoravitz, yes you are right that the notion maximal difference sounds here little bit ridiculous. But what does mean "how many more square..?" Why we subtract only these numbers 675 and 650? That's I can't grasp.

Comment: You could use the rewording of the question I gave in my first comment, or you could think of it as having a missing phrase: "How many more square inches of pizza can they purchase if they pool their money instead of purchasing alone [*assuming they buy the most amount of pizza possible with their money within the constraints in both cases*]."  To be fair, that *is* an assumption, but more than a safe assumption because otherwise the problem is uninteresting.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about buying $6$ small pizzas is correct but there is no incentive for that .

For $\$30$, each can get a large and a small $\quad \rightarrow 2(225+100)=2\times 325=650$

Combined, they can get $3$ large pizzas $\rightarrow 3(225)=675$

$$675-650=25$$

Your assumption about buying $6$ small pizzas is correct but there is no incentive for that .